# Bash script failing when run by cron - mktemp outputting nothing

Tags: bash, cron

I have a shell script, that works when I run it manually, but silently fails when run via cron. I've trimmed it down to a very minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "HERE:"
echo $(mktemp tmp.XXXXXXXXXX)
```

If I run that from the command line, it outputs `HERE:` and a new temporary filename.

But if I run it from a cron file like this, I only get `HERE:` followed by an empty line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
MAILTO=”me@example.com”

0 5 * * * /home/phil/test.sh > /home/phil/cron.log
```

What's the difference? I've also tried using `/bin/mktemp`, but no change.

Comment: Try changing your cron line to `0 5 * * * /home/phil/test.sh > /home/phil/cron.log 2>&1` so that you get stderr output in your log.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! It saved me a huge amount of head-scratching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the script tries to create the temporary file in root directory when it is started from cron and it has no permission to do that.

The cron configuration file contains `HOME=/`. The current directory is `/` when the script starts. And the template passed to `mktemp` contains file name only so `mktemp` tries to create the temporary file in current directory and it is `/`.

```
$ HOME=/
$ cd
$ mktemp tmp.XXXXXXXXXX
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. Doing `echo $(mktemp /home/phil/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX)` instead got things running.